# JS : How to trigger a Blur event with my code

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jform, calendar

I need help in triggering a Blur event attached to a calendar field.

The event I am trying to trigger is added in /media/system/calendar.js around line 1003

```
JoomlaCalendar.prototype._bindEvents = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.inputField.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
        var calObj = JoomlaCalendar.getCalObject(this)._joomlaCalendar;
```

The field the event is attached to is the Start Publishing field for my testing

```
<input type="text" id="jform_publish_up" name="jform[publish_up]" value="2012-01-04" size="22" class="inputbox" data-alt-value="2012-01-04" autocomplete="off">
```

My bit of JS where I am trying to trigger the Blur Event.

```
function addDate(target_field) 
{
    document.getElementById(target_field).value = currentDate();
    document.getElementById(target_field).blur();
}
```

The first line adds the current date to the field and works fine on other field types and will work on the calendar fields provided I place the cursor in the calendar field and leave(this is what triggers the Blur normally) at some point before I try to submit the form.

I have tracked it down to a few lines of code that need to run in the above blur event that allows my new value for the field to be saved and not reset back to the value it was before.

The second line is where I am trying to trigger the function and what is there is just the latest of things that don't seem to have any affect.

And for completeness here is my other test field that kicks of the process of adding the date to the start publishing field.

```
<input type="text" name="jform[note]" id="jform_note" value="3432" class="inputbox" size="40" onchange="addDate('jform_publish_up')" maxlength="255" aria-invalid="false">
```

This is a follow on question to this one for earlier in the week, [How to Update a field only when another filed is changed](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/26389/how-to-update-a-field-only-when-another-filed-is-changed) , and if I can save the dates then I can close it off.

Update 17/11 - This is the piece of code that I believe I need to run after my date  value is added to the target_field. /media/system/js/calendar.js at Approx. line 1013.

```
    if (calObj) {
        if (calObj.inputField.value) {
            if (typeof calObj.params.dateClicked === 'undefined') {
                calObj.inputField.setAttribute('data-local-value', calObj.inputField.value);
```

Without data-local-value being set, and this happens as the cursor leaves the field, then other processing in calendar.js that runs on Submit will revert the field back to the original value.
You can see this in any/most Joomla date fields if you inspect the event for the field you can this code under the third entry which is calendar.js

Comment: i’ve read the whole writeup of your situation but I still cannot really figure out what you would like to accomplish with calling the blur on that target field. Would you like to call an additional (callback) function when blur happens? Or you want to just blur the input field (to have the input field to lose focus)? (Maybe I’m stupid on this but I do not see it).

Comment: @Zollie I think what needs to happen is for target_field to lose focus after I have put my date value in to target_field.

Comment: @zollie I have added little more information to the original post. What I am trying to achieve is to simulate an end user selecting and then leaving the target date field after I put my value there.

Comment: I see your purpose a little bit more I think, but as I understand you would like to make the date field non-editable after the current date is inserted (or maybe I’m still misunderstanding it). So, after inserting current date, you could call `document.getElementById(“target_field").readOnly = true;`. I am not sure, but that came to my mind as I’m digesting your question.

Comment: @Zollie It is nothing to do with Read-Only. If I can't trigger this Blur event I would have to pop up a message to the end user to asking them to put the cursor in the target_field and then move to another field. Without this manual action, the value I put into the target field will not be saved. I want to do the trigger without making the User doing anything else. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I’m starting to see your issue more and more as I’ve read your posts about this like 5 times at least :). The admin changes the stock quantity value and when it is changed your script insert the current date into the date(calendar) field and your problem is that the inserted date is not saved at submission but reverted back to the original date. Do I understand that well? And you would like to trigger a blur on the date field which makes the inserted date’s saving possible. The part I do not understand: why the inserted date is not saved and why it is reverted back to the original field value?

Comment: So, what is causing the reset when you insert/define a new value for that date input field? Which filter of that field? Are you changing the dates in admin component or from site component side? And in which component, custom? Or this is in com_content?

Comment: @Zollie The reset appears to be caused by the value that I add to the target_field is not validated so on submit you can see the field revert to the original value. I am testing it on a standard date field in the front-end. If you add the JS in the third piece of code to a page with a date field and the onchange= to any other field you can recreate the issue. And with debugger on your browser set to Blur events you can see how the value is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.

My JS now looks like this

```
function addDate(target_field) 
{
    document.getElementById(target_field).value = currentDate();
    document.getElementById(target_field).focus();
    document.getElementById(target_field).blur();
}
```

and it works !!!

Comment: Your IDE might ask you declare the object as a variable and use it three times.  `let targetObj = document.getElementById(target_field); ...`

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too, since usually the blur is used together with focus... I have not checked that earlier in the day that is why I did not want to suggest this... well, the point is that you solved the issue, great. :)